# Regex - expression must start with "*."

Tags: regex

Can someone help my regex-challenged self with this? The match must start with `*.` and must be longer than two characters. Thanks!

Comment: "expression must start with “*.”". Says who? What exactly do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be fine with regex `\*\..+` or `(?=\*\.).{3}.*`

Comment: Why bother with an assertion? `^\*\..` And why downvote all competing answers without comment?

Comment: @minitech - match must start with... not line, so `^` is not a good idea. Also the match has to be at least 3-char long, so last dot should be `.+`. And no downvotes from me, guru....

Comment: I wrote it for a test, not a matching, so yes, `.+` is appropriate if you want to match something. As for `^`, it matches the start of the string in single-line mode. Contrary to what you have now, which will match it anywhere in the string, so that's not much better...

Comment: @user1436111: I know; it was Ωmega who downvoted the other answers. But s/he has taken the downvotes back now.

Comment: @minitech - first of all, you are rude, second of all, match inside of string is fine, as OP didn't specify that match should be at the begining of line. So `^` should not be there. If you believe my answer is wrong, post your own.

Comment: @Ωmega: I'm not being rude. Really. I'm saying that `^` doesn't *necessarily* match the beginning of the line; it depends on the matching mode. But yours is missing any kind of anchor whatsoever, so it's not much better. To cover all the bases, simply prefix it with `\A`.

Comment: @minitech - that would not find match in string such `hallo *.test`

Comment: @Ωmega: And the question gives/gave the impression that it shouldn't in the first place. I was just making a suggestion, but your answer was accepted so apparently it wasn't needed. (And the question [as originally worded, thanks for the edit] made me think that the regular expression itself needed to start with `*.` :P)

Answer (score 2):

So as * and . are both metacharacters they'll need to be escaped, plus a start of line anchor, leaving us with -

```
/^\*\./
```

Tested this on www.regextester.com

Answer (score 0):

What's the question? The asterisk tells the engine to match the preceding character zero or more times, in this case you have no preceding character. The period matches almost any character.

I don't know if that helps.